# How to handle browser authentication in headless mode in chrome using selenium web driver java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, headless

I am trying to enter the credentials for chrome browser in headless mode. I mean browser based authentication .
But I am getting error , not  able  to enter the credentials.

Could someone please help me on this.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using, the stack trace of the error you are seeing and the relevant markup you are interacting with.  If it's basic auth credentials you are trying to use, you probably want to use a proxy like the Browsermob proxy